# Check if ++ exists, If not, Then get the nearest

Tags: php

```
[     number      -      title     ]
[        1        -        t1      ]
[        2        -        t2      ]
[        5        -        t3      ]
[       13        -        t4      ]
[       22        -        t5      ]
```

for this part `$next_post = $number+1;` each time i click for example on a button, Go a step forward, But when it reaches `$number = 2;` it will give me 404 error since there is no `$number = 3;` How am i supposed to type a query to check if the next number doesn't exist, And then jump directly to the nearest number.

Comment: could you preprocess the numbers into an array using a regex then use a $next_post = $array[i] for the size of the array

Comment: @brad, hm, regex?

Comment: regex , regular expression to extract numbers between [ and -, then you could store those in an array

Comment: Something like: https://repl.it/HSMV ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your numbers in an array:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 5, 13, 22];
```

Now you can use `$next_post = $number[$i + 1];`